Sign in with Google aborts after login dialog
I'm trying to intiate google sign in through firebase . When I click on google sign in button , dialog box appears for me to choose from which account i have to login but after that this operation just gets abort .Even in the logcat , nothing is shown . Also when I try to login through Email it also fails
this is the code
class EmailSignIn : Fragment() {

private lateinit var binding: FragmentEmailSignInBinding
private lateinit var mAuth: FirebaseAuth
private lateinit var googleSignInClient: GoogleSignInClient


override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    binding = FragmentEmailSignInBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
        binding.lytIntro.visibility = View.GONE
        binding.layoutSignIn.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }, 5000)

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
        .requestEmail()
        .build()
    googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(requireActivity(), gso)
    binding.barEmailSignIn.visibility=View.INVISIBLE
    binding.btnForgotPassword.setOnClickListener {
        val forgotPassword=ForgotPassword()
        val navigationUseCase =
            switchFragmentUsecase(requireActivity().supportFragmentManager, R.id.logFragment)
        navigationUseCase.navigateToFragment(forgotPassword)
    }
    binding.btnGSignIn.setOnClickListener {
        signInGoogle()
    }
    binding.btnOtpSignIn.setOnClickListener {
        val otpSignUp=OTPSignUpFragment()
        val navigationUseCase =
            switchFragmentUsecase(requireActivity().supportFragmentManager, R.id.logFragment)
        navigationUseCase.navigateToFragment(otpSignUp)
    }
    binding.btnClickSignUp.setOnClickListener {
        val emailSignUp=EmailSignUpFragment()
        val navigationUseCase=switchFragmentUsecase(requireActivity().supportFragmentManager, R.id.logFragment)
        navigationUseCase.navigateToFragment(emailSignUp)
    }
    fillForm()
}


private fun fillForm() {
    binding.btnSignIn.setOnClickListener {
        binding.barEmailSignIn.visibility=View.VISIBLE
        binding.btnGSignIn.visibility=View.INVISIBLE
        binding.btnOtpSignIn.visibility=View.INVISIBLE
        binding.btnForgotPassword.visibility=View.INVISIBLE
        binding.btnClickSignUp.visibility=View.INVISIBLE
        binding.txtOptionsOR.visibility=View.INVISIBLE
        if (binding.editEmailTxt.toString().isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "Please enter your email id", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show()
            binding.barEmailSignIn.visibility=View.INVISIBLE
            binding.btnGSignIn.visibility=View.VISIBLE
            binding.btnOtpSignIn.visibility=View.VISIBLE
            binding.btnForgotPassword.visibility=View.VISIBLE
            binding.btnClickSignUp.visibility=View.VISIBLE
            binding.txtOptionsOR.visibility=View.VISIBLE
        } else {
            if (binding.editPasswordTxt.toString().isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(
                    requireActivity(),
                    "Please enter your password",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                )
                    .show()
                binding.barEmailSignIn.visibility=View.INVISIBLE
                binding.btnGSignIn.visibility=View.VISIBLE
                binding.btnOtpSignIn.visibility=View.VISIBLE
                binding.btnForgotPassword.visibility=View.VISIBLE
                binding.btnClickSignUp.visibility=View.VISIBLE
                binding.txtOptionsOR.visibility=View.VISIBLE
            } else {
                signInWithEmailAndPassword(binding.editEmailTxt.text.toString(),
                    binding.editPasswordTxt.text.toString())
            }

        }
    }

}

private fun signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: String, password: String) {
    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(requireActivity()) { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                binding.barEmailSignIn.visibility=View.INVISIBLE
                val intent = Intent(requireActivity(), HomeActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            } else {
                binding.barEmailSignIn.visibility=View.INVISIBLE
                binding.btnGSignIn.visibility=View.VISIBLE
                binding.btnOtpSignIn.visibility=View.VISIBLE
                binding.btnForgotPassword.visibility=View.VISIBLE
                binding.btnClickSignUp.visibility=View.VISIBLE
                binding.txtOptionsOR.visibility=View.VISIBLE
                Toast.makeText(
                    requireActivity(),
                    "Invalid email/password",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                ).show()
            }
        }
}

private fun signInGoogle() {
    val signInIntent = googleSignInClient.signInIntent
    launcher.launch(signInIntent)
}

private val launcher =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(result.data)
            handlerResults(task)
        }

    }

private fun handlerResults(task: Task<GoogleSignInAccount>) {
    if (task.isSuccessful) {
        val account: GoogleSignInAccount? = task.result
        if (account != null) {
            updateUI(account)
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), task.exception.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}

private fun updateUI(account: GoogleSignInAccount) {
    val credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.idToken, null)
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener {
        if (it.isSuccessful) {
            val intent = Intent(requireActivity(), HomeActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), it.exception.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show()
        }
    }
}

For OTP it is showing:

com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException: The sms code has expired. Please re-send the verification code to try again.


"operation abort" and "it fails" are really hard to help with, and Stack Overflow is a notoriously inefficient interactive debugger. If there is an error message, please share that. If there's no error message, debug the problem locally and tell us the result. If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the first line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

The Android docs have a great page on debugging your app to get you started with, including the section on working with breakpoints and inspecting varialbles.

for OTP it is showing , com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException: The sms code has expired. Please re-send the verification code to try again.
